# Stop form submission when there are still things to load

Tags: javascript, forms

I've written a code. I just want to see if it is efficient!!! Considering parallel downloading. 
I'm disabling button, then enabling it after **script** tag that processes the form.
I want to make sure user doesn't submit form before necessary files loaded, like **"checkform.js"**

```
<input type="text"><br>
<input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit">
<script>
    document.getElementById('submit').setAttribute('disabled','disabled');
</script>

<script src="checkform.js"></script>
<script>
    document.getElementById('submit').removeAttribute('disabled');
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:
1. Put disable in an attribute of submit btn.
2. Add onload attribute to checkform script tag.

```
<input type="text"><br>
<input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit" disabled="disabled">

<script>
    function checkformLoaded() {
        document.getElementById('submit').removeAttribute('disabled');
        // do whatever else you want after the script is loaded!
    }
</script>

<script src="checkform.js" onload="checkformLoaded"></script>
```

Comment: I had to add parenthesis to onload="checkformLoaded()" to work. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could also just wait for the whole `window` to load. This wil fire when all resources have been loaded, including your JS file that checks your form.:

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('submit').removeAttribute('disabled');
}
```

Comment: I think this one needs all images and other stuffs to be loaded and then user be able to click submit, but with code above, user can send data when checkform.js file is loaded.